# How to get raw url from http request message on self hosted server?

Tags: .net, wcf, http, rest

I'm using [HttpSelfHostServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostserver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to host a REST API and I would like to see the actual raw url requested by clients before it is parsed by the underlying infrastructure.

If I have understood things correctly: Under the hood **HttpSelfHostServer** uses WCF for accepting HTTP connections, which in turn uses [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**HttpListener** represent requests as instances of [HttpListenerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpListenerRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that has the promising [RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.rawurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which I suspect would carry the actual url (before parsing).

However, I don't know if it is possible to get access to the underlying **HttpListenerRequest** when using **HttpSelfHostServer**.

Since I don't have access to the actual raw url, the following requests have the same signature when they reach my code:

- `http://server/a?b`
- `http://server/a%3fb`

However, I want them to represent two different resources:

- `a?b` should represent a query `?b` on a resource named `a`
- `a%3fb` should represent a resource named `a?b`

Any help on how I could see the actual raw url when using **HttpSelfHostServer** or any other ideas on how to distinguish between these two requests would be greatly appriciated.

A good example on a REST API that support this kind of naming is the [Get Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440.aspx) API in Windows Azure:

- `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?timeout=1` goes to the blob named `myblob` with query parameter `timeout=1`.
- `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob%3ftimeout=1` goes to the blob named `myblob?timeout=1`.

I need to support a similar naming scheme in my API.

After investigating this further I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible to see the raw url.

This is unfortunate because the **RawUrl** property of the underlying **HttpListenerRequest** have the exact value I'm looking for.

It would be helpful if anyone could confirm that it is in fact impossible to retrieve the raw url of requests when using **HttpSelfHostServer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this further I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible to see the raw url.

This is unfortunate because the RawUrl property of the underlying HttpListenerRequest have the exact value I'm looking for.

It would be helpful if anyone could confirm that it is in fact impossible to retrieve the raw url of requests when using HttpSelfHostServer.